# How to align logo with nav bar?

Tags: html, css, web, header, navbar

I simple cannot figure out how to align my h1 header (referred to as logo) with my nav bar that I want to appear to the right. I've been trying to make the h1 header display: inline, and the navbar float: right, but the navbar seem to appear **under** my h1 header. I've also tried to float the h1 header to the left. Here is my code:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width: 900px;
}


/* header*/
header {
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
    width: 90%;
}

h1#logo {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    display: inline;
}


nav {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
header a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

and the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Carl-Emil | Jazzpianist, musikunderviser</title>
        <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <header>
                <h1 id= "logo">Carl-Emil Dons</p>
                <nav id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href= "about.html">Om Carl-Emil</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "music.html">Musik</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "underviser.html">Underviser</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "transcriptions.html">Transkribtioner</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add `snippet`, so we can help you faster.

Comment: Your question answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104599/problems-aligning-my-logo-with-the-navigation-bar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems aligning my logo with the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104599/problems-aligning-my-logo-with-the-navigation-bar)

Comment: Snippet? How does that work? Can't seem to find the function when editing my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have `</p>`, it's out of place. You must to delete this for your browser does not take it. It is misplaced in the HTML.

Try the new HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Carl-Emil | Jazzpianist, musikunderviser</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <header>
        <h1 id= "logo">
        Carl-Emil Dons
        <nav id="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href= "about.html">Om Carl-Emil</a></li>
            <li><a href= "music.html">Musik</a></li>
            <li><a href= "underviser.html">Underviser</a></li>
            <li><a href= "transcriptions.html">Transkribtioner</a></li>
            <li><a href= "contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake, which I am! Thank you!

Comment: @Calle No probs ! Good luck for the future !